# On radio button check/uncheck, load/hide partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I want to load or hide partial view whenever a radio button is checked or unchecked. I currently am kind of blank on what should I do.
I currently have this in view

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Response", FormMethod.Post))
{     
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Isattending, "RadioButtonQuestion")
                </div>

            </div>

}
<div id="provideDateTime">
   //load partial view here
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:radio[name=Isattending_0]').change(function () {

            if ($("#Isattending_0").is(':checked')) {
                //show partial view. 
                //should call a method in controller that renders partial view
                //don't know what to do
            }
            else {
                //hide partial view
            }
        })

    })

    </script>
```

The editfor helper generates two radio buttons with id `Isattending_0` and `Isattending_1`, whenever the Isattending_0 is checked the partial view should be shown, and upon uncheck the partial view should be hidden, and by default it is checked.

This is method in controller that should be called from above script

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AttendeeAvailability(Guid appointmentId, Guid attendeeId)
{
    var attendeeAvailability = new AttendeeAvailableDateTime
    {
        AppointmentId = appointmentId,
        AttendeeId = attendeeAvailability
    };
    return View(attendeeAvailability);
}
```

PS: I tried to show/ hide a text(Hello world) inside the div `provideDateTime` for a start with following javascript code, but it didn't work, the text hello world always appeared, even if the radiobutton is checked or unchecked

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input:radio[name=Isattending_0]').change(function () {

            if ($("#Isattending_0").is(':checked')) {
                $("#provideDateTime").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#provideDateTime").hide();
            }
        })

    })

    </script>
```

Rendered Html in browser for radio buttons
[image]

Comment: yes, I even checked the id in rendered html by browser, will post a picture of generated html in browser, just a min.

Comment: According to your screenshot, the name of the buttons is 'Isattending', but your code `$('input:radio[name=Isattending_0]')` is looking for buttons with name Isattending_0 ... Try and change it to only 'Isattanding' :)

Comment: but can i do it by id as well? because both have same name but different id and I want to load partial view based upon, radio button with id `Isattending_0`

Comment: I just made a test, and for some reason it doesn't fire a "change" event when the 2nd button is selected, so I would suggest you go with listening for the name. Please see http://jsfiddle.net/Fizk/TmHvC/1/

Comment: Change it to $('#Isattending_0').on('change', function() {}); instead. Also check in firebug if your code is actually getting called

Comment: @Gjohn what the difference between doing on change and checking if it is checked or unchecked?

Comment: @Biplov13 - you will still need to check if the radio button is checked or unchecked. My comment was more to change your event handler. The on('change') is a replacement for your .change(function()) handler that you have there. As I stated in the post, pull up firebug and put a breakpoint on that event handler then see if it hits it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
 $.get('/Controller/Action',function(data){
                     $('#provideDateTime').html(data);
              });
        $('#Isattending_0').change(function () {

            if ($("#Isattending_0").is(':checked')) {
              $.get('/Controller/Action',function(data){
                     $('#provideDateTime').html(data);
              });
            }

        })
   $('#Isattending_1').change(function () {

            if ($("#Isattending_1").is(':checked')) {

                     $('#provideDateTime').html('');

            }

        })
    })

    </script>
```

Comment: based upon the comment on my question, I realised that both radio button has same name, but they have different id. So `Isattending_0` is id not the name, will this still work?

Comment: also i have to provide parameters to the controllers method

Comment: actually why can't you write two events?

Comment: so how would the two events look like?

Comment: but shouldn't i pass the parameters to the controller's method? I think i should

Comment: yes you should like '/Controller/Action?para1=data1&para2=data2'

Comment: thanks it worked but by deafult, i want the partial div to be shown as the radio button is checked

Answer (score 0):

Just do a jQuery Post call to the action in your controller that is serving up the Partial View. Make sure the return type on your Action is ActionResult - this will return the result.

```
$.ajax(type: "POST", 
       url: "{route to your action}", 
       data: {data}, 
       success: function (response) // This response will actually be HTML of your partial View
       {
           $("whatever-div-you-want-your-partial-view-to-appear").html(response):
       }
```

Comment: I think you meant ajax get call but anyways, on radiobutton change call the controller method through ajax get call?

Comment: @Biplov - the ajax call should be inside your if statement where it checks if the radio button is checked or not.

Comment: and by default when the page loads for first time, the radio button is checked, for that how can i make the partial view appear? right now it works only on change event

Comment: @Biplov13 For that you will need to put your ajax call into a function of its own. Then make sure you call it on the load and also inside the radio button's event handler.